# Replace Character From String in PHP

Tags: php

I have string in PHP like below

> C:\xampp\htdocs

I want output of it using str_replace like

> /xampp/htdocs

I am trying it like below

```
$path = getcwd();
$new = str_replace(array("C:", "\"), ("","/") $path);
echo $new;
```

but its giving me error like below

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '","' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expect
>       ing ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\install-new.php on line 16

Let me know what is wrong with it.

Comment: You need to escape the backslash, otherwise it is escaping the quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you escaped a double quote. 
You need to add an backslash to your second expression like that:

```
$path = getcwd();
$new = str_replace(array("C:", "\\"), ("","/") $path);
echo $new;
```

Comment: Yes! its working fine....Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing array declaration on the 2nd argument, as well as a comma before the 3rd argument `$path`.  Lastly as noted in the comments, the `\` needs to be escaped otherwise it escapes the closing quote:

This:

```
$new = str_replace(array("C:", "\"), ("","/") $path);
```

Should be:

```
$new = str_replace(array('C:', '\\'), array('','/'), $path);
```

Comment: its still same error.